# Cloud storages (dropbox, sync, etc), how sync nested folders?

Tags: sync, dropbox, cloud-storage

I am faced with the problem using cloud storages. I want keep my files in that way:

```
Project 1 Root > Design
Project 1 Root > Programming
Project 1 Root > bookkeeping
Project 2 Root > UI
Project 2 Root > Etc
Project 2 Root > Workflow
```

and give other users permissions for either Root folders or subdolders. Root folders for managers, subfolders for specialist workers.
But cloud storages don't allow share nested folders! I checked Dropbox and Sync.com

> "You are already sharing a folder inside. Nested share folders are not
>   supported"

they say. 
My style of folder structure seems very logical and easy. How can I avoid my problem with such cloud storage restriction?

Answer (score 0):

If you can not have nested shared folders, then you have to share folders at the same level for Managers and Specialists. Managers will have to subscribe to three folders for each project. It is a one time subscription, so it really shouldn't too inconvenient to click on two more folders to allow editing. Now, I can certainly understand this workaround being an issue if you have more than three sub-folders per project!